# Как написать программу на Python, чтобы после каждой 2й кавычки ставилась точка с запятой

Tags: python

вход будет такой(с переходом на след строку) считывать с файла .txt

```
ratio "2"
speed "53"
bonk "12"
```

выход должен быть таким (без перехода на след строку)

```
ratio "2"; speed "53"; bonk "12";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На экран:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
         print(f"{line.strip()}; ", end="")
print()
```

В строку:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    s = f.read().replace("\n", "; ")
```

или

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    s = "; ".join(map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readlines()))
```

Comment: cпасибо большое )

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто методом `replace` менять переход строки на точку с запятой

```
new_str = old_str.replace('\n',';')
```